# Sympy cannot perform simple exponential summation

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to do the following summation, which should be straightforward to do in sympy

```
import sympy as sp
w = sp.Symbol('w')
a = sp.Symbol('a')
sp.summation(sp.exp(-a*w),(w,0,sp.oo))
```

But sympy does not evaluate it to the simple result

```
exp(a)/(exp(a)-1)
```

Instead it keeps the sum unevaluated.
How should I force sympy do this simple summation?